# Not printing to browser scope element

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this filtered collection:

```
this.myForm.get('filterProduct').valueChanges.subscribe(
    value => {
        data.Stores.forEach(filtered => {
            console.log(filtered.Products.filter(val => value.slice(1) >= val['Price']))
            console.log(filtered);
        });
    });
```

which print nothing to browser  in my way:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let product of filtered">
        <img src={{product.ProductImage}}>
        <p>Product Price: {{ product.Price }}</p>
        <p>Product Title: {{ product.ProductTitle }}</p> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

In your template, you are trying to iterate through filtered array whereas from your code sample, it looks like you have not assigned any value to this array.

Answer (score 0):

> Make the following change in your code

```
this.myForm.get('filterProduct').valueChanges.subscribe(
    value => {
      data.Stores.forEach(filtered => {
        //USE FOLLOWING LINE
        this.filtered = filtered.Products.filter(val => value.slice(1) >= val['Price']);
        this.priceFilter = this.filtered.products; //Add to price filter.
     .
     .
     .
```

Comment: Thank you!  if so, if I want that every time this.filtered get arguments (which happens after clicking for "price" )to print arguments from "filtered" ?with the HTML below it didn't work

Comment: `filtered` has this arguments[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbH74.png) while selecting [price from a list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ouf6w.png) with `<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <select name="Price" formControlName="filterProduct">
       <option *ngFor="let k of priceFilter  | groupBy: 'Value' | keyvalue">
         <div>
      <ng-container *ngFor= "let i of k['value']">
         <span>{{i['DisplayText']}}</span>
      </ng-container>
      </div>
       </option>
       </select>
   </form>`

Comment: Changed the answer as per your comment

Comment: @not working..I need that every clicking on price the relevant products will show